# Minimizer of parametrized convex function

Tags: inequality, optimization, convex-optimization, parametric, parametrization

So let us consider the following minimization problem parametrized in $z$

\begin{align*}
\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}} L_z(x) = \frac{1}{2} \left(x - z\right)^2 + |x|
\end{align*}

The goal is to then find the minimizer when $z \in [-1,1]$. I will lay out my solution and why I am uncertain about how I got there. So if we find the gradient to look for critical points, we get that

\begin{align*}
\frac{d L_z}{dx}(x^*) = 0 = 
\begin{cases}
(x^* - z) + 1 & x^* \geq 0 \\
(x^* - z) - 1 & x^* < 0
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

and so we find that the case-wise critical point is

\begin{align*}
x^* = \begin{cases}
z - 1 & x^* \geq 0 \\
z + 1 & x^* < 0
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

If we look at the case that $x^* \geq 0$ and the fact that $z \in [-1,1]$, we find that $-2 \leq x^* \leq 0$. If we look at the latter case and the fact that $z \in [-1,1]$, we find that $0 \leq x^* \leq 2$.

Taking both of these inequalities into account, we find that $0 \leq x^* \leq 0$ and thus $x^* = 0$ $\forall z \in [-1,1]$. This is validated if one write a program to solve the problem.

My issue is I feel like I should have been explicitly taking into account the case inequalities such as $x^* \geq 0$ for the first case and $x^* < 0$ for the second case. Can anyone explain why this is or is not important to do and how I should be using it if it is necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minor error in your solution is that you've determined the derivative when $x=0$.  This function is not differentiable at this point.

Suppose $x^\star>0$.  Then, as you've shown, then $x^\star=z-1$.  If $z=1$, then we see that $x^\star=0$, which is a contradiction.  If $z<1$, then $x^\star<0$, which is also a contradiction.  Therefore, $x^\star\leq 0$.

Suppose that $x^\star<0$.  Then, as you've shown, $x^\star=z+1$.  If $z=-1$ then $x^\star=0$, which is a contradiction.  If $z>-1$ then $x^\star>0$, which is a contradiction.

When $z\in[-1,1]$, our suppositions that $x>0$ or $x<0$ lead to contradictions.  Therefore, $x=0$.

Thus, $x=0$ is the optimal point for all cases.

Comment: Makes perfect sense, thank you!

Comment: @spektr  I fixed some errors.  I'm happy to help.  :)